# Saving file behaves differently on iPhone and simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void) saveJsonToFile {
    //Original document from Resources folder
    NSString* saveFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
    //NSLog(@"Saving...%@", saveFilePath);
    NSData* jsonData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];

    BOOL success = [jsonData writeToFile:saveFilePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(success ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```

On the simulator, it will log Yes. When deploy to my iPhone, it logs No. Anyone know why is that and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but I think you're trying to write to your bundle, instead of your Documents or Temp directories. iOS prohibits that, but might only be enforcing that on the actual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not permitted to write into your own app bundle. (And a good thing too! Modifying your own app would be a terrible thing to be able to do.) Write into the sandbox (e.g. the documents folder or the application support folder).

Comment: Here's my explanation of good places to write to and how to get references to them: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_the_sandbox